# spring boot starter inject bean based on property

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Recently, I'm working on developing a spring boot starter providing `ServiceA` for client code. I want to provide config properties as:

```
my.namespace.serviceA=impl1    #or other implemtations

my.namespace.serviceA.impl1.prop1=ServiceAImpl1Prop1Val
my.namespace.serviceA.impl1.prop2=ServiceAImpl1Prop2Val
# some other properties of ServiceA
```

I also add several Bean Classes with annotation `@ConfigurationProperties` for different implementations of `ServiceA`, as springboot will automatically load those properties into those beans.

My starter wants to give client code an interface of `ServiceA`, so that it can be used as：

```
@Autowire
private ServiceA serviceA;
```

I need to gives an factory method like:

```
@Bean
public ServiceA serviceA() {
    //TODO load my.namespace.serviceA and create the corresponding 
    //instance of ServiceA Implementation with given properties
}
```

Since the properties **varies** according to different implementations, is there an elegant way to implement such factory method leveraging property beans with `@ConfigurationProperties`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the looks of it you are 90% at the answer.

Instead of creating the bean manually, you can mark ServiceA as a component and the Spring component scan will create the bean for you.

Looking at an implementation of ServiceA

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "my.namespace.serviceA.impl1")
@Component
public ConcreteA implements ServiceA {
    private String prop1;
    private String prop2;
}
```

#### Edit

Based on the fact that you want one instance of ServiceA, you still need to annotate your class with `@ConfigurationProperties` but remove `@Component`.

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "my.namespace.serviceA.impl1")
public ConcreteA implements ServiceA {
    private String prop1;
    public void setProp1(String s) {
        prop1 = s;
    }
}
```

You must have at least setters for your properties.

Then in your config class where you create your bean

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "my.namespace")
@Configuration
public SomeConfig {
    private String serviceA;

    public void setServiceA(String s) {
        serviceA = s;
    }

    @Bean
    public ServiceA serviceA() {
        if (serviceA.equals("ConcreteA1")) {
            return new ConcreteA1();
        } else {
            return new ConcreteA2();
        }
    }
}
```

The approach of using an if statement actually breaks the open / closed principle and introspection is a better approach, but I think you get the idea.

Comment: But I don't want to create too many instances of different `serviceA` implementations but only one instance of Type `serviceA` according to the first property. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Ok, I understand better now. You will need to add some logic to create the instance of the correct type in your factory method. The `@ConfigurationProperties` annotation should still work. I will update the answer a bit

Comment: That works. Thanks a lot. As for the if statement, I think using reflection to create a n instance might avoid that :> I just wonder how spring knows to inject properties when I use `new` operation to create instance maintained by my code.

Comment: Reflection will fix the "problem", but depending on your system it may not be a real problem at all. As for how Spring sets the value. Because of the `@Bean` annotation, Spring does additional processing on the instance you return. During that step the properties are set, after your instance is returned.